# Jquery causing form inputs to inherit error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When entering a valid email; the continuation of the form is shown/ slides up. Awesome! However, the next inputs have inherited the `.tobefixed` (error) class.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQaSr/43/) to show what I'm dealing with. How do I only show the `.tobefixed` error class to show after an attempt to submit has been made?

If I could get another set of eyes on this, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: Does removing `css` method solve the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/ZGDMP/

Comment: DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SQaSr/44/ this shows that it is an issue with how you handle the Apply click, i'll resolve it and post an answer, otherwise feel free to look at the above and see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apply button is causing the form submit even to fire because it is inside the form.

If you give that button a dummy form name it will disconnect from the startform.

```
<button **form=""** data-next-id="form1" validationDiv="signup" class="continue button button-action apply">Apply</button>
```